# View PDF in monotouch

Tags: pdf, controls, xamarin.ios

I need to do the following with a PDF in monotouch, any help appreciated.

1. How do I display a PDF stored on disk?
2. Same as above, but displaying a specific point in the document.
3. If the user holds down their finger on the document (iPad equivalent of right click) how do I get the document location (for use with #2)
4. Does this control allow me to get a list of words in the document + their document location again for use in #2

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CoreGraphics with a pdf graphics context, which you can get with UIGraphics.BeginPDFContext.